# How to recover login window in Liferay?

Tags: authentication, liferay

I faced interesting situation when I was developing a Liferay portal:

I accidentally removed the Liferay login window! On Liferay everything is configured when you're logged in, but what to do if you remove the portlet where the login used to be and logout?

*(By removing the portlet I don't mean undeploying but removing the instance from the live version of Liferay. So when you come to the main page, no login button is shown anymore!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution: *http://www.myliferayserver.com/c/portal/login* shows a login window although it would be deleted from the main page. After login to that page I could add the login back to its original place to main page of my portal.

Comment: I would also like to note, that if you haven't changed the theme there is a log in button somewhere else on the page, usually in the dock or a simple link (depending on the version).